# Where is the mistake in the following DC circuit analysis?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

In the following circuit, I'd like to calculate the potential difference $V_{BA}$.

One way is to solve the circuit, by calculating all the currents $I_1, I_2, I_3$. The system of equations is:

$\{I_1 + I_2+I_3 = 0, 6 - 2 I_2 +2 I_1=0, 12 - 2I_3 + 2I_2 = 0\}$.

The solution is $(I_1, I_2, I_3) = (-4, -1, 5) mA$. Then $V_{BA} = 2 I_3 = 2 \times 5 = 10V.$

I'd like to solve the same problem via a different route. I put the GND at the negative pole of $-6V$ source. Then for point A, I write:

$\frac{0-V_A}{2} + \frac{V_A - 6}{2} + \frac{18-V_A}{2} = 0$, giving me $V_A = 12V$. Then $V_{BA} = V_B - V_A = 18 - 12 = 6V$, that is clearly wrong. Where is my mistake ?

[image]

Comment: For the drawn reference direction, $I_2(ma) = \frac{6 - V_A}{2}$, i.e., you have a sign error.  Also, though DC circuit analysis isn't entirely off-topic here, it's *more* on topic at the EE sister site:  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Duh! Epic pebkac :( @AlfredCentauri if you provided the same sentence, as this comment, for an answer, I would accept it (so that at least you get the credit). Also, thanks; I wasn't aware of the EE site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the drawn reference direction, $I_2(ma) = \frac{6 - V_A}{2}$, i.e., you have a sign error.